# How can I center my drop down menu?

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I can't figure out how to center the tabs of my drop down menu, also, every time i change the font or size of the text, the down downs disappear when i put the cursor over them. Please help!here is the css:

```
 /*----- MBT Drop Down Menu ----*/

#mbtnavbar { 
background: #000000; 
width: 100%; 
color: #FFF; 
    margin: 0px; 
    padding: 0; 
    position: relative; 
    border-top:0px solid #960100; 
    height:100%;
  }

 #mbtnav { 
    margin: 0; 
padding: 0; 
} 
 #mbtnav ul { 
float: left; 
list-style: none; 
margin: 0; 
padding: 0; 
} 
 #mbtnav li { 
list-style: none; 
margin: 0; 
padding: 0; 
    border-left:1px solid #000000; 
    border-right:1px solid #000000; 
    height:35px; 
 } 
 #mbtnav li a, #mbtnav li a:link, #mbtnav li a:visited { 
color: #FFF; 
display: block; 
 font: normal 12px Trebuchet, Trebuchet;    margin: 0; 
padding: 9px 12px 10px 12px; 
text-decoration: none;

} 
#mbtnav li a:hover, #mbtnav li a:active { 
background: #333333; 
color: #FFFFFF; 
display: block; 
text-decoration: none; 
    margin: 0; 
padding: 9px 12px 10px 12px; 


 }
#mbtnav li { 
float: left; 
padding: 0; 
} 
#mbtnav li ul { 
z-index: 9999; 
position: absolute; 
left: -999em; 
height: auto; 
width: 160px; 
margin: 0; 
padding: 0; 
} 
#mbtnav li ul a { 
width: 140px; 
} 
 #mbtnav li ul ul { 
margin: -25px 0 0 161px; 
 } 
 #mbtnav li:hover ul ul, #mbtnav li:hover ul ul ul, #mbtnav li.sfhover ul ul, #mbtnav li.sfhover ul ul ul { 
left: -999em; 
  }      

 #mbtnav li:hover ul, #mbtnav li li:hover ul, #mbtnav li li li:hover ul, #mbtnav li.sfhover ul, #mbtnav li           li.sfhover ul, #mbtnav li li li.sfhover ul { 
left: auto; 
} 
#mbtnav li:hover, #mbtnav li.sfhover { 
position: static; 
}
#mbtnav li li a, #mbtnav li li a:link, #mbtnav li li a:visited { 
background: #000000; 
width: 120px; 
color: #FFFFFF; 
display: block; 
font:normal 12px Helvetica, sans-serif; 
margin: 0; 
padding: 9px 12px 10px 12px; 
    text-decoration: none; 
z-index:9999; 
border-bottom:1px dotted #333;

} 
 #mbtnav li li a:hover, #mbtnavli li a:active { 
background: #333333; 
color: #FFF; 
display: block;     margin: 0; 
padding: 9px 12px 10px 12px; 
    text-decoration: none;
```

Comment: Please post relevant HTML.

Comment: First narrow down which section of CSS is the issue and show us the HTML.  This should be easy if you also tell us what you've already tried.

Comment: recommend creating a pastie/jsbin/online editing example of your ode including relavant hml and simplified css rules to isolate issue